# App crashes on clicking on textView in fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I'm creating an app in which there are three tab activity.In tab Three i have a textview name as login text whenever user click on this text a new activity should be opened but app crashes when we click on this. 
I have done many research to resolve this problem but i'm unable to resolve at last i'm here for the solution of my problem Please help.
Thanks in advance.
This is my loginActivity.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText email_Id;
    private EditText password;
    private TextView sign_Up;
    private Button sign_In;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     //   if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            // directly start user profile activity
       //     finish();
         //   startActivity(new Intent(this,userProfileActivity.class));
       //}
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        email_Id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_id);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        sign_In=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_In);
        sign_Up=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        sign_In.setOnClickListener(this);
        sign_Up.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    private void user_Login(){
        String email=email_Id.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass_word=password.getText().toString().trim();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            // email is empty
            Toast.makeText(this,"please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;// to stop the function from executation.
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_word)){
            // email is empty
            Toast.makeText(this,"please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        // here if everything ok the user will be register
        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User,please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass_word)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            // start user profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userProfileActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view==sign_In){
            // start user profile activity
            user_Login();
        }
        if(view==sign_Up){
            // go to registeration page
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,FragmentThree.class));
        }

    }

}
```

[this is declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K0Kt.png)

[This is my login method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpNaP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following line in your code throws the exception:

```
 sign_Up.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The problem is, that `sign_Up` is `null`!

You set `sign_Up` with: `sign_Up=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);`

Make sure, that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` (activity_login) is the right one. If, try to clean and rebuild your project and try again.

---

**Update:** It is possible, that `sign_up` should be a button? If, you make a wrong cast!

Change the TextView in this line:

`sign_Up=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);`

to Button, like this:

`sign_Up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);`

Comment: You have two pictures in your question post. But both pictures are the same. Please update it. The problem is in the loginActivity!

Comment: I have updated and added my login activity. please help

Comment: Please comment out this line:  sign_Up.setOnClickListener(this); and try, whether the exception goes away

Comment: Now the sign_Up will be inactive how to make it active.

Comment: Have you seen the updated answer? Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: I have tried as you suggested but Sign_up button is not responding.

Comment: AHHH!! ;) In the last comment you say "Sign_up button"! Remove this line: sign_Up=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up); and add this line: sign_Up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_up); I think you try to cast a button to a textview...

Comment: sorry for that was typing error by me, actually i'm using onClickListner on a textview named as sign_up so as user can click on this an go to other activity and i can not use button instead of this as it'll effect my ui.

Comment: Okay, have you tried to set the OnClick in your xml file, like this:  android:onClick="onClick" and then in you activity: public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
          }